# Port AngularJS Web Application to Windows Phone8

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing web application using AngularJS and jQuery and use Node.JS as web server.

I found the video from Microsoft that we can port web application to Windows Phone 8 as HTML5 app easily just copy and past code to Visual Studio but it cannot be run in both emulator and device.

I'm still confuse that it can be worked? Because my web cannot run as static without using Node.JS but I've tried making static web and port into Windows Phone.... It works!!

I would like to know how can I port the my current web app into Windows Phone? Do I need to install Node.JS into there? (I'm kidding....)

Thanks to advice :)

Comment: I've also tried this in the past without success.. I don't think it's possible, my suggestion, create a responsive website and load this website into your app. Good luck :-)

Comment: What doesn't work? You'll need to have a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.105).aspx) hosted in your phone application which points to your Node.Js web application.

Comment: I don't know what video you're referring to either?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I mean the really app that can send to windows store not the web that open with IE. For the video --  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNY4oZByTko

Comment: You can just put the web pages as assets in your phone project if they're static.